# Trying to delete record but EntityState.Deleted deletes all records

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, scaffolding

I'm trying to delete a record if it exists or add it if it doesn't. The adding works fine but if I have three records with the same Id but three different FavId even though Dtl shows the correct record it still deletes all three. I've tried various switching around but with the same end result.

```
using (var context = new DataContext())
{
    var query = from st in context.Favourites
                where st.Id == id && st.FavId == fav_id
                select st;
            
    var Dtl = query.FirstOrDefault<FavouritesModel>();
    if (Dtl != null)
    {
        var favDetails = new FavouritesModel { Id = id, FavId = fav_id };
        context.Entry(favDetails).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    } 
    .
    .
}
```

The model looks like this and there are only three fields with Id as primary key although FavId should be a key value too but I don't think that's why it is failing.

```
public partial class FavouritesModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; } = null!;

    public string FavId { get; set; } = null!;

    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Can someone who may have had this problem tell me what I have missed so that I can just delete the required record and not all of them.

Comment: What do you mean by "deletes all records"? What is the **actual** SQL command being sent to your RDBMS?

Comment: `= null!;` <-- Please don't do this. If you want to suppress nullability warnings you should use `#pragma warning disable` - not cargo-cult syntax (or _better yet_: use constructors properly - EF Core supports instantiating Entity classes via constructors now)

Comment: Ok, noted, I will do that in future but can you help with my question?

Comment: Dai, delete all records is just as it suggests and I explained. I have three records but want to delete one but it 'deletes all records' as in deletes all three!!

Comment: Are you using SQL Server? If so, can you do an XEvents trace to see (and share with us) the actual SQL commands being sent from EF?

Comment: Also.... where-and-when are you calling `SaveChanges` or `SaveChangesAsync`? So far there's nothing in your code you've posted that would make any changes to persisted data at all.

Comment: You really should add explicit EF attributes (like `[Key]`, etc) and with explicit FK property/columns, because otherrwise EF has to do _a lot of guesswork_ w.r.t. what the actual SQL `CREATE TABLE` looks like, and often those guesses are not what you want.

Comment: I've actually fixed it myself and it was pretty easy, I simply added FavId as another primary key and now it works fine with no code changes necessary! Word to the wise Dai, not everything has to be so complicated most people like to keep things relatively straightforward.

Comment: Tables/entities cannot have multiple _primary_ keys - but they can have _secondary_ keys (aka `CONSTRAINT UNIQUE`). That said, I still wouldn't trust EF to generate a proper table design though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sorted the problem by adding FavId as a primary key along with Id, so no changes necessary just a change to my SQL DB.

Comment: If `FavId` is the PK, then what does `Id` represent? Why not remove the `Id` property/column now then? I stress that there's no advantage (and plenty of downsides) to having multiple redundant secondary-keys.